# Module compiled with Swift 5.2.4 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3 compiler even with Xcode 11.7 command line tools

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

I try to compile an app on Xcode 12 but I have this issue: "Module compiled with Swift 5.2.4 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3 compiler" on my custom framework.

I don't understand why Xcode try to compile with Swift 5.3 than I have set the command line tools on Xcode 11.7 ([settings locations Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnhiO.png)).

Thank you in advance and don't hesitate to ask me for more information.

Comment: If you are compiling within Xcode 12, then it will be using Swift 5.3. However it you are compiling using the command line i.e. using xcodebuild then you should be OK

Answer (score 1):

If you are building dependencies for your app using `xcodebuild` (e.g. using Carthage), you need to make sure your command line tools version matches your xcode version before you build your dependencies.

For example, I have Xcode 12 installed at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
```

so before I build my app using Xcode 12 I need to run

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and then rebuild my dependencies using `xcodebuild`. Similarly I have Xcode 11 installed at

```
/Applications/Xcode11.7.app
```

so before I build with Xcode 11 I need to run

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode11.7.app/Contents/Developer
```

and then rebuild my dependencies with `xcodebuild`

Comment: Thank you, I thought the command line tools on Xcode impacted on the Swift version inside Xcode. So, I can't use Xcode 12 to compile in Swift 5.2.4.